# query function breaks mysteriously

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Database class which has multiple functions to execute queries. One of them is the simplest of them all:

```
public function query($query) {
    return $this->_link->query($query);
}
```

$this->_link->query works in other cases, so it should work here. From a file that has an instance of a class, I do this:

```
function createLineChart() {

    $query = "select * from tags";
    $result = $db->query($query);

    // do something with result
}

createLineChart();
```

but it breaks on the $result line. The query is also valid, I've testid it. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is `$db` is out of scope of the `createLineChart()` function. You can either use the global method:

```
function createLineChart() {
    global $db; // <-- make the db var become available
    $query = "select * from tags";
    $result = $db->query($query);

    // do something with result
}
```

Or pass the `$db` object to the function as an argument:

```
function createLineChart($db) {

    $query = "select * from tags";
    $result = $db->query($query);

    // do something with result
}

createLineChart($db);
```

More info about [Variable Scope on the Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed the problem. $db was declared outside of the function.

Answer (score 2):

```
function createLineChart() {
    var_dump($db);
    // this should probably return 'undefined'
    global $db;
    // so globalize it!
    $query = "select * from tags";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    // do something with result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$db` is a class variable, then you need to refer it as:

```
$result = $this->db->query($query);
```

Comment: I think the `createLineChart` function might be outside of the class, in which case `$db` will not be defined. The OP says *From a file that has an instance of a class*

Comment: This isn't the problem at all. `createLineChart()` is clearly not a method of an object, but a standard user defined function not linked to any class.